# Should we add tags representing years

Tags: discussion, tags

I agree that having specific tags such as [london-2012](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/london-2012) is good for the site, but not at the current time. We don't have enough users that use them, so maintaining such user-friendly tags would be an overkill; specially because they will probably not be used a few weeks after the event is over.

So I'm proposing the idea of having tags for years, and use them with the sporting event required. For example if we add [2014](/questions/tagged/2014) to our tags, then it could be used with the other ones that already exist to address questions regarding [2014](/questions/tagged/2014)[world-cup](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-cup)or [2014](/questions/tagged/2014)[olympics](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympics)or [2014](/questions/tagged/2014)[nba](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nba)or [2014](/questions/tagged/2014)[tour-de-france](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tour-de-france)... . This way we don't need to make or keep tags that won't be used after the event is finished, and if someone happens to have a question about a tournament/competition in the past, they can use the year-tag as well as the name of the tournament/competition.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is nice in theory, but not certain about its practicality (playing advocate here).

A small subset of our questions will fall under the category of tagging a year. You mention specific, user-friendly tags because they will probably not be used a few weeks after the event is over. I agree that this circumvention would allow to not make/keep useless tags in the future. I agree it would be more useful, and it would collect sporting events per given year under one roof...but is it useful enough to begin rolling out this practice?

One thing that sets Sports Stack Exchange is providing useful questions. Outside of trivia and history, how can a question be useful **today?** For the [2002](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2002) [nba](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nba) Western Conference Finals, I suppose a question could be asked about how that series implemented fair officiating policies and procedures in the NBA...and it be useful today...but the year is more referential than significant in terms of content (and, in my opinion, wouldn't necessitate the use of a year tag)...

I'll let the community ponder this one. Personally, it isn't a bad idea, just unsure about its practicality in the long run.